# Bottle Marking Pen?

Tags: bottles, labels

I recently had the idea that, instead of taping my bottles, and marking with a sharpie, it would be very handy to use something like a 'grease pencil' to mark up the bottle with the relevant info.

Unfortunately, black on brown, or even red on brown, doesn't seem to be very useful to me.

Does anybody know about something like this, in white, that could be used?  I've tried a white crayon, without success.  And I've heard of chalk markers, but they won't work when submerged in ice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling 'White Grease Pencil' will give you several hundred options. Here's [Amazon's offering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049D5NYW).

Comment: indeed...I just tried that( I was doing my research before/while you posted yours).  Linked to one in particular.  The bigger question is "does it work for our application" ?  I don't see any reason why not, but, I'd be curious to know if there's any experience ?

Comment: I like my link (http://www.ecrater.com/p/9680837/white-12-china-markers-wax-grease) better (only because of the pencil type), but you deserve credit for the answer above myself...

Answer (score 2):

I've found sharpie on the cap to work well enough for my needs. Sometimes I get confused with just 1 letter (was P the Porter or the blonde we named Pam?) but for the most part, it works fine.

Not really the answer you're looking for...

Comment: no, not really the one I'm after.  I'm already doing that, but was looking for extra detail, without the hassle of making actual labels (glue, etc).  Tape is better, but will also fall off in the ice bath, so not perfect either.  Stronger tape would work, but also leaves a glue residue that I'd need to deal with....so, Back to the original 'hope', some kind of white grease pen....simple, cheap, quick, water-proof, and easy to clean!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.ecrater.com/p/9680837/white-12-china-markers-wax-grease

This appears to be what I'm thinking about...but, has anyone ever TRIED it ?

Comment: I have used a Sharie brand white china marker with perfect success.  I write on carboys and bottles with it.

Answer (score 2):

Try kegworks.com

Search "marker" Comes in  silver (for bottles) or gold (for glasses). Wipes off with cooking oil. I have not personally tried this product.

Comment: That looks cool! I'm going to have to check those out...

Answer (score 0):

I have a "Metallic" colored Sharpie that I could use for that - I don't because I want to re-use the bottles though. You could try that color though.

Comment: nope...the point was to find a removable, but semi-permanent (would survive a casual dip in an ice bath, but not a scrubbing in hot, soapy water).  Thanks, though, for your reply.  You're quite right in that it would work, but only for a single application.